# PySide: How to have Input Mask and Place Holder Text at the same time

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qlineedit

I'm trying to make a lineEdit widget have place holder text (look like 'MM/DD/YYYY') when not in focus and have input masking (looks like '  /  /    ', or you can put in slashes through other means) when in focus.

Currently the input mask `setInputMask('99/99/9999')` takes precedence and I can't figure out a way to put a hasFocus (or similiar) signal on a LineEdit widget.

How would you implement both of these functionalities in one widget?
Would it be easier to leave the place holder text as is and create a method that adds in a slash after entering a certain number of characters?

Also, the flicking cursor is really thick when you set a mask. What's up with that and how do you revert it?

Full code:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def myChanges(self):
        self.lineEdit.installEventFilter(self.lineEdit.setInputMask('99/99/9999'))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText('MM/DD/YYYY')

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(557, 351)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 130, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 130, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 557, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.myChanges()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a custom behavior of a widget you must create a class that inherits from this, in your case of QLineEdit. To get your specific objective you must use the focusInEvent and focusOutEvent methods as described in the following section:

```
class LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QLineEdit.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setPlaceholderText('MM/DD/YYYY')

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.setInputMask('99/99/9999')

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        self.setInputMask('')
```

And then you should change to:

```
self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
```

to:

```
self.lineEdit = LineEdit(self.centralwidget)
```

Answer (score 0):

Novice here, I was looking for just that. [eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44580857/1247325) pointed in the right direction, but a few things may have changed. `QtGui.QLineEdit` is not a thing strictly speaking, or else it's just a subtlety between PyQt (what I use here) and PySide.

`QLineEdit` has methods `setFocus`, `setFocusPolicy`, `setFocusProxy`, but unfortunately none to help us here. Subclassing is the simplest answer (that I know). This is for a "general" answer, not for patching a ui file:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw

class NewLineEdit(qtw.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.setInputMask("99/99/9999")

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        self.setInputMask("")
```

Then, in your `MainWindow` or whatever:

```py
dateField = NewLineEdit(self)
dateField.setPlaceholderText("MM/DD/YYYY")
```

It can be refined without having to hardcode the mask in the bespoke widget.

```py
class NewLineEdit(qtw.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent, mymask, *args, **kwargs):
        self.mymask = mymask
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.setInputMask(self.mymask)

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        self.setInputMask("")
```

Then

```py
dateField = NewLineEdit(self, "99/99/9999")
dateField.setPlaceholderText("MM/DD/YYYY")
```

PyQt 5.15.9
Qt 5.15.10
Python 3.10.13